# Как из массива полученного через json_encode из GET запроса сделать запрос к БД?

Tags: php

Есть GET запрос вида: **http://127.0.0.1/test.php?key=foo&value=bar**.
Необходимо что бы при переходе по данной ссылке в БД (noSQL), создавался ключ **foo** со значением **bar**. Как реализовать данную возможность?
C помощью `json_encode($_GET)` получаем строку `{"key":"foo","value":"bar"}`. Как можно данную строку превратить в значения для передачи их в дальнейшем в БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вам json_encode? У вас же уже есть массив ключ-значение

```
insert_into_no_sql_db($_GET['key'], $_GET['value']);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = '{"key":"foo","value":"bar"}';
$obj = json_decode($str);
echo $obj->key;
echo $obj->value;
```